# NoReboot=false does not work with CreateImageRequest

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

When creating an Ami image of an instance with the AWS SDK for net, the CreateImageRequest does not respect the NoReboot=false property. The idea is to have AWS reboot the instance being imaged, before the imaging process starts. In  the Aws Ec2 console, I can see that the instance is not rebooted. Here is my code:

```
CreateImageRequest createimagerequest = new CreateImageRequest()
{
    Name = BackupName,
    Description = "Backup of " + BackupName,
    InstanceId = inst.InstanceId,
    BlockDeviceMappings = blockdevicemapping,
    NoReboot=false
}; 
 CreateImageResponse CreationResult = ec2Client.CreateImage(createimagerequest);
```

Does anybody know if this is meant to be this way, that the NoReboot has now function when used in the Aws SDK for Net? (dll-file in use: AWSSDK.EC2.3.3.124.4)

Comment: By default this property is set to false, which means Amazon EC2 attempts to cleanly shut down the instance before image creation. Are you sure everything else goes right? I mean the image is created, maybe something else is failing.

Comment: Yes, I know NoReboot is set to false by default, and the image is being created alright. Everything seems fine and dandy, but I can observe with certainty that the instance itself is not being rebooted. Could this be a case for a bug report?

Comment: In some scenarios, instance is rebooted but does not show up as rebooting on AWS console, for example when you use reboot command. Can you check the uptime on your server to check whether it was rebooted or not?

Comment: The instance is in the `running` state, not the `stopped` state, before you initiate image creation?

Comment: Ahh!.... Aaaahha! Blimey! Juned Ashan is right. I was too hasty. I did not observe the quick change in the Aws console, where it blinks just once at Alarm status. I really had to examine the system event log to se that the reboot just happened. So it's allright then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion: *The NoReboot=false does in fact work with CreateImageRequest*. 
Lesson learned: Keep the nightly coding sessions at shorter stretches, just to have the mental capacity to think about checking your system logs (thanks Juned for pointing that out).